# Get the maximum value of state for li items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose, I'm having an unordered list for tabs as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I'm making a list as active based on click. So, when a user clicks on a `li`, it will be marked as active and `this.state.selected` will be equal to the number of the `li`. For example, on clicking on the first `li`, `this.state.selected` will be equal to `1` and so on.

Is there a possible way to find out the `maximum state` possible for selected?

Example, if the `ul` has three `li` tags, then the `maximum state` for `selected` will be `3`.

Comment: The maximum state would be the number of relevant elements. Can you show your initial attempted code, so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `this` is a reference to the `<ul>`, I'd suggest:

```
this.state.maximum = this.children.length;
```

Or, in the event there might be children not to be counted, you can pass a CSS selector to `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve only those children you wish to find:

```
this.state.maximum = this.querySelectorAll('li.classToFind').length;
```

Or, you can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to retain only those elements you wish to count, based on a property of the element nodes, for example keeping only those element nodes with a property of 'keep' equal to 'true' (as a simple demonstration):

```
// Array.from() turns the NodeList returned by this.children
// into an array, in order to easily use the methods of the
// Array prototype,
// Array.prototype.filter() is used to filter out those elements
// for which the assessment in the anonymous function returns a
// false, or falsey, value:
this.state.maximum = Array.from( this.children ).filter(
  function(node){
    return node.keep === true;
  }).length;
```

Or, rewriting the above to use arrow functions:

```
this.state.maximum = Array.from( this.children )
                          .filter( n => n.keep === true ).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possible way to find out the maximum state possible for
>   selected?
>
> Example, if the ul has three li tags, then the maximum state for
>   selected will be 3.

So, you want to find out the number of children of the `ul`?

```
<ul id="ul1">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This much code should do

```
alert( document.getElementById( 'ul1' ).children.length );
```

Comment: I don't want to find the number of children. I want to find out the maximum possible state for the li. Will it be a proper way to set the state to document.getElementById( 'ul1' ).children.length?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh you said `if the ul has three li tags, then the maximum state for selected will be 3` in this case my solution should work. since it will give number of number li tags inside ul

Comment: I get that. I'm asking will that be a proper way or is there any better way to do this :)

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh I am not sure how you define better. This one is simple and will work across browsers.